# Pentaho: Generate a report first and then serve it in different formats

Tags: pentaho

I've created a report using the Pentaho Report Designer and saved the .prpt file. I've included the file in a Java EE application and am using the Pentaho API's to display the report in different formats i.e. HTML, PDF, Excel, etc.

Is there a way I can generate the report once and then serve it up in different formats i.e. have the SQL run only once. Having it set up this way would be a huge performance improvement.

Comment: A work-around i can think of is to store the result data in the temp table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at report caching. A new feature since platform version 4.5 - user reports can be cached, but it is only on a per user per session basis. So if you're not maintaining a session the data wont be cached?

It may be you need to tweak the cache configuration.

http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fperformance_tuning_guide%2Ftopic_reporting_caching.html